# Implementing a wcf service the right way

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I am just learning WCF and I am trying to implement a WCF service on a dummy project I am working on and I wana do this right.

My project contains a DataAccess project that has an entity framework repository that is resposible for accesing data in the database.This is how the model and interface look like:

```
public partial class BookModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string BookUrl { get; set; }
}

public interface IBookRepository
{
    IEnumerable<BookModel> GetBooks(int pageNumber, int numberOfBooksOnPage);
    IEnumerable<BookModel> GetBookByCategory(int categoryId, int pageNumber, int numberOfBooksOnPage);
    BookModel GetBookById(int bookId);
    int CountBooks();
    int CountBooksByCategory(int categoryId);
    void AddBook(BookModel book);
    void UpdateBook(BookModel book);
    void DeleteBook(int bookId);
}
```

Now when I implement the wcf service I have to define the service contrat and the data contract.The thing is that this two are exact duplicates of my curent model and repository , so I am not really sure what to do.

This is what I have so far but I am not sure this is the right way:

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BookUrl { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
interface IBookService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks(int pageNumber, int numberOfBooksOnPage);

    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Book> GetBookByCategory(int categoryId, int pageNumber, int numberOfBooksOnPage);

    [OperationContract]
    Book GetBookById(int bookId);

    [OperationContract]
    int CountBooks();

    [OperationContract]
    int CountBooksByCategory(int categoryId);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddBook(Book book);

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateBook(Book book);

    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteBook(int bookId);
}
```

Is it a good Ideea to move the model and repository into the wcf service?

Or should I create duplicates for this two classes in my wcf project that just call the methods from the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a thing that you should understand, implementing your WCF service - it sends only **data** between your client and service in messages, but **not the implementation of your classes and interfaces**, which you should describe before you start to consume you service. To setup it properly you have to **a**) make a ServiceContract on your server side **b**) merge it on your client side. After doing this your service will know how to put the data of your contract instances into messages on server side and to get this data from the messages and create contract instances on client side.

If the data you send is standart .NET object (which can be serialized), both server and client will know its structure, and will be able to work with it. But if it is your own class - you have to make it as DataContract, so that client would understand how to create instances of this class from messages.

So, yes, if you use Book class in your ServiceContract methods, it should be marked as DataContract. But you dont have to create its dublicate. Your service only has to see it and it has to be marked with [DataContract] attribute. By doing this, when your would create reference from client to your service, for example by svcutil, it will create the same Book class on your client side. The structure of this class will follow your datacontract and its datamembers.